# Can I query a YAML dataset in Python?

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

Similar to [Is there a query language for JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777455/is-there-a-query-language-for-json) and the more specific [How can I filter a YAML dataset with an attribute value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768663/how-can-i-filter-a-yaml-dataset-with-an-attribute-value) - I would like to:

- hand-edit small amounts data in YAML files
- perform arbitrary queries on the complete dataset (probably in Python, open to other ideas)
- work with the resulting subset in Python

It doesn't appear that [PyYAML](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyYAML/) has a feature like this, and today I can't find the link I had to the YQuery language, which wasn't a mature project anyway (or maybe I dreamt it).

Is there a (Python) library that offers YAML queries? If not, is there a Pythonic way to "query" a set of objects other than just iterating over them?

Answer (score 1):

I don't thing there is a direct way to do it. But PyYAML reads yaml files into a dict representing everything in the file. Afterwards you can execute all dict related operations. The question [python query keys in a dictionary based on values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166508/python-query-keys-in-a-dictionary-based-on-values) mentions some pythonic "query" styles.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use jsonpath? Yes, that's meant for json, not yaml, but as long as you have json-compatible datastructures, this should work, because you're working on the parsed data, not on the json or yaml represention? (seems to work with the python libraries `jsonpath` and `jsonpath-rw`)

Answer (score 1):

[bootalchemy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bootalchemy) provides a means to do this via SQLAlchemy. First, define your schema in a SQLAlchemy model. Then load your YAML into a SQLAlchemy session using bootalchemy. Finally,  perform queries on that session. (You don't have to commit the session to an actual database.)

[Example](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bootalchemy) from the PyPI page (assume `model` is already defined):

```
from bootalchemy.loader import Loader

# (this simulates loading the data from YAML)
data = [{'Genre':[{'name': "action",
                   'description':'Car chases, guns and violence.'
                  }
                 ]
        }
       ]

# load YAML data into session using pre-defined model
loader = Loader(model)
loader.from_list(session, data)

# query SQLAlchemy session
genres = session.query(Genre).all()

# print results
print [(genre.name, genre.description) for genre in genres]
```

Output:

```
[('action', 'Car chases, guns and violence.')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following tools:

- [yq](http://mikefarah.github.io/yq/) for CLI queries, like with *jq*,
- [yaml-query](https://pypi.org/project/yaml-query/) another CLI query tool written in Python.

Comment: Please don't just post some link/tool/library as an answer. [Demonstrate how it solves the problem in the answer itself.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605/13138364)